# How do I combine ramda with recompose?

Tags: reactjs, ramda.js, recompose

I have this component;

```
const ReposGrid = R.pipe(
    R.prop("repos"),
 // branch(R.isEmpty, renderComponent(Loader)),
    R.map(Repo),
    ReposWraper
)

export default ReposGrid
```

This works fine but I want to render loader component if `repos` is empty. My `branch` from recompose just doesn't do anything. It doesn't show Loader neither displays `repos` when it's loaded. Can I apply `R.ifElse` here?

Comment: Is `ReposGrid` a higher order component or a component itself? Can you provide a minimal example of `ReposWraper` (typo there btw) and `ReposGrid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be mixing up ramda's `pipe`/`compose` and recompose's, and the arguments they take. Your chain is made up of a mix of higher order components and functions operating on props. It's best to keep the data handling in `mapProps`/`withProps` etc.

You might be able to achieve something similar to what you're after like this:

```
import { map, evolve, propSatisfies, isEmpty } from 'ramda'
import { compose, branch, renderComponent, mapProps, renameProp } from 'recompose'

const Repo = (repo) => <div>Repo {repo}</div>
const Loader = () => <div>Loader</div>
const RepoGridBase = props => <div>{props.children}</div>

const ReposGrid = compose(
    branch(
      propSatisfies(isEmpty, 'repos'),
      renderComponent(Loader),
    ),
    mapProps(evolve({
      repos: map(Repo)
    })),
    renameProp('repos', 'children')
)(RepoGridBase)

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReposGrid repos={[]} />
      <ReposGrid repos={['one', 'two']} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

(this will throw key warnings, you'd probably be better of doing the `map` inside of a component explicitly)

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/l93kwm6nj7)